# How to apply applyPattern for SimpleDateFormat in java?

Tags: java

I am trying to add a new pattern to the date display but I am not getting the result that I am expecting:

Here is my code:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.S");
    sdf.applyPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
     Date date_out = null;
    try {
        date_out = sdf.parse(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date)).setText(date_out.toString());
```

I want the output to look something like this: 03 Oct 2011

However this is the output tat I am getting: Oct 03 00:00:00 GMT+ 11:00 2011

How do I reach the desired output?

EDIT:
I solved this code by adding this line:

```
sdf.format(date_out);
```

instead of setText()

Comment: Your code doesn't output anything...

Comment: I added one extra line to the code. It is where the date is shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Date.toString();`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString%28%29) does **always** format your String that way. You should a SimpleDateFormat to format the `Date` object to the String you want.

The JavaDoc of the [`Date.toString();`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString%28%29)  method says:

> Converts this Date object to a String of the form:
>
> ```
> dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy
> ```

Comment: Thank you. That was it. I ended up using sdf.format(date_out) and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use two `SimpleDateFormat` objects. One for parsing the input and an other one for formatting the parsed `Date` object to String.

```
final String inputDate = "2011-05-08T11:12:13.0123";
final SimpleDateFormat inputParser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.S");

Date date_out = null;
try {
    date_out = inputParser.parse(inputDate);
} catch (final ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

final SimpleDateFormat outputFormatter = 
    new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy", Locale.US);

final String result = outputFormatter.format(date_out);
System.out.println(result);
```

Output:

```
08 May 2011
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`Date.toString()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString%28%29) method formats the string like that (check the api documentation).

You do not actually need to use `applyFormat(...)` in this case. You want to parse one format and output it in another format.

To parse the date (given the string: `2011-10-03") use can use the format`"yyyy-MM-dd"`and when you output the`Date`you want to use`"dd MMM yyyy"`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

    SimpleDateFormat inputFormat  = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMM dd");

    Date parsedDate = inputFormat.parse("2011-10-05");

    System.out.println(outputFormat.format(parsedDate));
}
```

Outputs (on US locale):

```
2011 Oct 05
```